# How to do group recursive feature elimination?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I want to do group feature selection using recursive feature elimination(RFE). For example I have a data as follow

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X,y=make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=20)
```

What i want to do is that instead of applying RFE on single column, i want to do in group of columns. For example, my first 10 columns are one group, 10-20 are second group and so on. So I want is to eliminate one group instead of one column in each iteration. So if Ipass `n_features_to_select=5` i should get 50 columns, (5 groups) instead of 5 columns.

```
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(estimator, n_features_to_select=5)
```

Comment: There might be two ways to accomplish this:

Comment: (1) `step` parameter of `RFE`/`RFECV` prunes off `n` features in each iteration. So you might get something *close* by setting step to be the minimum number of features per group. If you have 5 groups represented with 50 columns, then set `step=10`.

Comment: (2) `importance_getter` can be set to a callable. If there is a known ordering to the groups (e.g. columns 0-4 are group-1, 5-9 are group-2, etc.) then you might write a callable that takes the `feature_importances_`/`coef_` attributes and the indexes to remove the group with the lowest average feature importance.